# set action of the form in classic asp, while on selecting the value in the dropdown

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I want to change the Form action, while selecting the drop down's element.
Example:
for button:

```
<input type="submit" name="straction" id="straction" value="Submit">
```

Now i want, how to set the action for Drop down?

Thanks for helping.
jagadi.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>change form action</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="frm1" action="default.html">
            <select id="actions" onchange="document.getElementById('frm1').action=this.value">
                <option value=""></option>
                <option value="action1.asp">one</option>
                <option value="action2.asp">two</option>
                <option value="action3.asp">three</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit" name="straction" id="straction" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

If using jQuery then change the

```
<select id="actions" onchange="$('#frm1').attr('action',this.value)">
```

Comment: Since the drop down is part of the form you can have such thing: `onchange="this.form.action=this.value;"`